# Button toggle-text on multiples

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button set to toggle the height of a div with the class `read-more` when clicked, however I have multiple versions of the same code on each page as the posts are generated via a wp_query. How can I adjust the below code to only toggle the read-more div that it is in the same code block as?

**HTML**

```
<article>
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <p>Intro text</p>
    <div class="read-more">
        <p>Toggle Text</p>
    </div>
    <button class="toggle-text">Read More</button>  
</article>

<article>
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <p>Intro text</p>
    <div class="read-more">
        <p>Toggle Text</p>
    </div>
    <button class="toggle-text">Read More</button>  
</article>
```

**JS**

```
/* Toggle event to show/hide 'read more' content */
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button.toggle-text").click(function(){
        $(".read-more").animate({
            height: "toggle",
            opacity: "toggle"
        }, 400);
    });
});

$(function(){
   $(".toggle-text").click(function () {
      $(this).text(function(i, text){
          return text === "Read More" ? "Read Less" : "Read More";
      })
   });
})
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/921qau49/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
$(".read-more").animate({
```

to this:

```
$(this).siblings(".read-more").animate({
```

[Here is your updated **JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/921qau49/1/)

The above code looks for elements with the `read-more` class that are under the *same* parent.

Answer (score 1):

`.read-more` is immediate previous sibling of clicked button. You can target it with clicked button context `this` along with `.prev()` in button click handler. or you can traverse to closest article element and then find `.read-more` in it. also you do not need to separate handlers to achieve this. you can write the code in single click handler.

```
 $(".toggle-text").click(function () {
   $(this).prev(".read-more").animate({ 
        height: "toggle",
        opacity: "toggle"
    }, 400);
  $(this).text(function(i, text){
    return text === "Read More" ? "Read Less" : "Read More";
  })
});
```

**OR:**

```
$(".toggle-text").click(function () {
   $(this).closest('article').find(".read-more").animate({ //or  
        height: "toggle",
        opacity: "toggle"
    }, 400);
  $(this).text(function(i, text){
    return text === "Read More" ? "Read Less" : "Read More";
  })
});
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/oxyw5ah8/)**

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! However, that working demo seems to open and close the toggle?

Comment: @dungey_140: sorry. shared the wrong link earlier. first click handler should be removed. check the updated fiddle.